# How to apply animation to a large number of static mesh actors in a single blueprint? UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-blueprint

I'm working on a project in Unreal Engine 4 where I receive all the static meshes and objects from the designer classified and named correctly, for example she sends me a TV Unit and I want to find all the cabinets in this TV unit and apply the open and close animation to them.

What I tried to do so far is that I was able to detect all the cabinet doors in the TV unit in the level blueprint, based on the names of objects I received, which I already know is a bad idea but bear with me just for the sake of debugging, and I tried to apply the animation when that specific object is overlapped.

The problem is I can't seem to find a way to make the overlap event to work on all of these objects in the foreachloop, how can I attach the event to all of these object? and what is the best practice for something like this?

[My level bluprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJSq.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question with some code?

Comment: @cslotty I did add an image of my level blueprint and the function that I'm stuck in

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but here it goes:
Remember! A for loop will always bind the event to all elements in the array but if you take the element from the loop and use it in your event only the last one will be used.
Also I did not understand how can you play an animation on a static mesh , you will need skeletal meshes.

Please follow up to my answer , lets fix this . thanks.

Comment: Why is it a for loop if it's only gonna attach to the last object only? It seems like the loop is redundant this way and I don't think it's actually the case! Also of course you can apply the animation to a normal static mesh actor by using timelines or matinees so I don't need a skeletal mesh.

Comment: Ok I was thinking it was an animation from maya etc , btw it will bind to the last object only , to test this , in your binding event print the name of the object that is being overlapped and you will see it will only print one name.

Comment: A good practice will be to create a parent class and bind the event to it , then create all child class and they will all be binded to that event . ty